# pulling my hair on codeigniter upload

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload, selected

So I keep getting an error saying that I did not choose a file to upload. I followed the codeigniter's site example, and searched a lot of topics with no success. PLease help me identify what I'm missing or doing wrong. It's just a simple upload of an xml that is like couple kb's.

The controller:

```
<? if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class upload extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index(){

        $this->load->view("uploadPage", array('error'=>''));

    }

    function theUpload(){
        echo "uploading";
        $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            $error=array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view("uploadPage", $error);
            echo "no upload";
        } else{
            echo "file uploaded";

        }
    }       
}
?>
```

The HTML:

```
<body>

    <?php echo $error;?>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/theUpload');?>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File">
    </form>
</body>
```

If it helps, here's my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kayokee/ci/
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#’system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn’t in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename ’application’ to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404′s
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a requirement, but I would try setting `$config['allowed_types'] = 'xml'; ` . Are you doing anything in your `.htaccess` to append a trailing slash to urls? That has been known to screw up file uploads.

Comment: (sigh) no it still says that I didn't select a file :(

Comment: I just copied your code into my codeigniter, and it ran fine. I would remove all your echo calls, as they could be screwing things up. Then, after the line `if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){` try adding this code `print_r($_FILES);` , and tell us what the output is.

Comment: I'm not getting any output, the HTML in Firebug console says Array(), that's it

...here's the URL: http://honciano.com/kayokee/ci/upload

I also have 777 on the folder named uploads, it sits in ../kayokee/ci/

Comment: so I've been looking around to try to continue to figure this out... and this is what I put as the first line of the "theUpload()" function:

$file = $this->input->post("userfilea");
  print_r("file2:". $file);

I'm getting a blank array. I think it's clear that the form from the View is not reaching the controller. Why would this happen? I've tried all the suggestions here, and it's not work, but it seems to work on other's computer....

Comment: Well, I got it to work, apparently jquery was interfering. After removing that, I was able to get closer to the resolution. Now I'm stuck with The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. I saw that updating the library to the latest should fix it...but it didn't...

Comment: Okay, I've narrowed it down to the XML mime. I managed to upload a Jpeg, but when I use XML, it so doesn't work.

Comment: It could be that the XML file isn't having it's header set properly, is the file being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the following:

```
  <? if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index(){

        $this->load->view("uploadPage", array('error'=>''));

    }

    function theUpload(){
        echo "uploading";
        $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $filedata = array(        
          'userfile_name' => $_FILES['userfile']['name'],
          'userfile_size' => $_FILES['userfile']['size']
        );
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload($filedata)){
            $error=array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view("uploadPage", $error);
            echo "no upload";
        } else{
            echo "file uploaded";

        }
    }       
}
?>
```

Make sure the userfile is the name of the file type input you have in your HTML!

Comment: This one gives me an error 500. It was the $t()fig array, I switched it back to $config and it came out fine.

the $filedata stuff gives me an error, it says "Message: Undefined index: userfile"

Answer (score 0):

The controller class name upload first word should be capital like Upload.
 The folder must be writable and the path can be absolute or relative.
like 
`class Upload extends CI_Controller`